# 32 bit computer to USB

Tags: usb, 32-bit

I need to download a 32 bit Ubuntu to USB. Version 16.04.5 requires a bittorrent client to install. Will Rufus.ie work instead?

Comment: Please tell us about your computer: brand name and model.

Comment: BitTorrents clients are to download a file, any file, including the Ubuntu ISO. But you can download the ISO directly. The BitTorrent client is NOT for burning an ISO to USB.

Comment: I think Ubuntu 18.04 has no 32bit, Lubuntu 18.04 does. Try UNetbootin with Windows or mkusb with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I went with an old 32 bit version of Linux Lite after the creator, Jerry Bezencon, responded telling how to find the older 32 bit version (at SourceForge). It worked! Thanks to all those who responded!